# 404 error when trying to access admin page magento

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, admin

I changed the base url for the admin page in magento admin end but now it says 404 error.

The error page read's this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted";i:1;s:2887:"#0 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(772): Zend_Uri::factory('www.vitaminbeas...')
#1 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(588): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('web', NULL)
#3 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/community/All4coding/Core/Helper/Data.php(64) : eval()'d code(55) : eval()'d code(51) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(220): Mage::getBaseUrl('web')
#4 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/community/All4coding/Core/Helper/Data.php(64) : eval()'d code(55) : eval()'d code(51) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(345) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(30) : eval()'d code(20) : eval()'d code(22) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(172): All4coding_Core_Helper_Data::getHost()
#5 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/community/All4coding/Core/Helper/Data.php(64) : eval()'d code(55) : eval()'d code(51) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(345) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(30) : eval()'d code(20) : eval()'d code(22) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(19): All4coding_Core_Model_Observer->_updateLicenseKeys()
#6 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): All4coding_Core_Model_Observer->preDispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(All4coding_Core_Model_Observer), 'preDispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#11 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#12 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/vitaminb/public_html/s/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/magento/index.php/beastadmin/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Can Anyone let me know how to change it back please. I tried looking in core_config_data for the custom url but it's not there.

Comment: Questions about Magento should be asked on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

In core_config_data the entries are (usually) on line 5 and 6 of the table but don't have to be, and look like this

id | scope | scope_id | path | value

5 | default | 0 |web/unsecure/base_url | http://magento.local/

6 | default | 0 |web/secure/base_url | http://magento.local/

in future it is best to always backup the magento db before changing anything like this so you can recover easily. In phpadmin just do an expoert of the whole db.

Comment: I need to access the admin url not the main page url. I found the admin url part and changed use custom to 0 and deleted the custom path names

Comment: my page: www.vitaminbeast.com and I ususally login by http://s.vitaminbeast.com.au/magento/index.php/admin/  but as you can see if you click it It has the 404 error inside the page?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Go to the magento/var directory and jus delete the cache directory

Comment: did that but nothing changed